# DBRef lazy loading in Spring data mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to use @DBRef with lazy loading, but did not working. I use Spring data mongodb (version 1.4.1.RELEASE).

This is my sample:

```
public class Person {

@Id
private String id;
private String firstname;
private String surname;

// Spring create proxy
@DBRef(lazy = true)
private List<Address> addresses;

public boolean hasHomeAddress() {
    if(addresses != null) { // this condition is not required, because "addresses" is proxy
        for(Address address : addresses) { //in this line - NullPoinetrException
            if(AddressType.HOME.equals(address.getType())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//getters/setters
}


public class Address {

@Id
private String id;
private String locality;
private String street;
private AddressType type;

public static enum AddressType {
    HOME, OTHER;
}

//getters/setters
public AddressType getType() {
    return type;
}
}
```

When i run this code:

```
Person person = personRepository.findOne(personId);
if(person.hasHomeAddress()) {
  //do something
}
```

than i'll get NullPointerExcetpion. Exception is throw when execute this code:

```
for(Address address : addresses)
```

What i doing wrong? Maybe this is a bug of spring data mongodb?

Comment: Not a Spring data bug. Just initialize the list as in `private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();`. This will do. Thus, a List object will be proxied.

Comment: Even if the list "addresses" has been initiated, exception NullPointerExcetpion is throw when iterate list.

Comment: @user3527319 Have you found a solution?